# How can i get the accurate results from sql query

Tags: sql, sql-server

Given: I have two tables, first table includes the list of the branches and the second table includes the assigned branches to employees.

Problem: I can't have the accurate results of the query, it generates the assigned branches only. I want to see the full list of branches but the assigned branches is already omitted.

This is the SQL I tried:

```
SELECT Idx,BranchName
FROM BranchList
WHERE Idx IN (SELECT Idx FROM AssignedBranch where EmpId = 20001)
```

Please see the screenshot for the results I want to get:

[image]

Comment: try WHERE Idx NOT IN (SELECT Idx FROM AssignedBranch where EmpId = 20001)

Comment: what is `TABLE1` and `TABLE2` ? And what is the expected result ?

Comment: TABLE 1 is BranchList and Table 2 AssignedBranch

Comment: And what is your requirement of the query ? And also the expected result

Comment: I posted an image , you can refer to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your description and the image contradict. You said `I want to see the full list of branches` but the image only show branch that is not assigned

based on the image, the query should be

```
select *
from   BranchList b
where  not exists
       (
           select *
           from   AssignedBranch a
           where  a.Idx = b.Idx
           and    a.EmpId = 20001
       )
```

Comment: @momonsterr . . . `NOT EXISTS` is much preferable to `NOT IN` with a subquery (because it handles `NULL` values intuitively).  I think this should be the accepted answer.

Comment: @GordonLinoff thanks for the info. I updated the accepted answer . Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Your Description and Result image are different. As per your image result, the query will be

```
SELECT Idx,BranchName
    FROM BranchList
    WHERE Idx NOT IN (SELECT Idx FROM AssignedBranch where EmpId = 20001)
```